# While commenting on a Wordpress post, it gives a "406 Not acceptable" error

Tags: wordpress

When someone is trying to comment on my posts, they get a"406 Not acceptable error". However, I can fix this by disabling the Modsecurity, But I am afraid to do so. Is there any fix for this issue?
Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does it happen for any input? maybe you can do some JavaScript sanitization of the input before submission.

Comment: CRS dev-on-duty here. Even this is probably not an OWASP Core Rule Set error I would like to help you, because you mentioned, that it works without ModSecurity. When ModSecurity blocks, it typically sends an error 400 (bad request) or 403 (forbidden). To help you, could you please provide some logs from the error.log??

Comment: hi, this is the error I got in the error.log   >>>>>   [22-Jun-2022 07:29:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  printf(): Too few arguments in /home/herbhome/public_html/wp-content/themes/hitmag/footer.php on line 63

Comment: This is not a ModSecurity error in the error.log file. ModSecurity would also log there. So I think it's not a ModSecurity error and unfortunately, I'm not able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

When someone types an address of a website on the browser, the web browser sends a request to the server in the form of **Accept Header** and when the server doesn’t find any file type browser asks, it displays 406 error.

Most of the times, the error occurs due to mod_security, a protocol web hosting companies apply to protect a website. If it tracks any violation of the rules, a 406 error or not acceptable error is shown on the screen. So, you can contact your hosting provider and they will take care of it.

I am providing the code that will help others to resolve the issue

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngineOff
SecFilterScanPOSTOff
</IfModule>
```